# Android as Webservice Server?

Tags: java, android, web-services, http, webserver

maybe contrary to others, I´m thinking of running a webservice Server on Android. Is there any Library that supports this? I think ksoap2 e.g. is only for consuming webservices, not for serving them, right?

And, if thats not possible without lengthy coding, I just need to run a HTTP Server on Android and receive binaries with it (via POST).

Can anybody give some hints?

Cheers,
Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I´ve dismissed the thought of implementing it with a Webservice on Android-side and just managed to do it via Socket-Communication and a self-designed protocol, quite like this:

```
public class AsyncTaskSocketServer extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, Integer> {

private int id;
private String TAG = "AsyncTaskSocketServer";

private AsyncTaskSocketServer() {
    super();
    Random generator = new Random();
    id = generator.nextInt();
    Log.d(TAG, "created with id: " + id);
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... ports) {

    int port = ports[0];
    Log.v(TAG, "Trying to start on port: " + port + " with id: " + id);

    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        while (!isCancelled()) {
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            try {
                Log.v(TAG, "Listening on port: "
                        + port);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                String str = in.readLine();
                publishProgress(str);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v(TAG, "Exception while socket.accept"+ id);
            } finally {
                client.close();
            }
            client.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(TAG, "Exception in SocketServer creation" + id);
    }
    return port;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    String message = values[0];
    try {
        NetworkQueue.MESSAGE_IN_QUEUE.put(message);
        Log.v(TAG, "received: " + message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.log("AsyncTaskSocketServer: Exception while writing to IN_QUEUE");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First result of http server android: http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/

Comment: seen that already, thanks. but does it support Webservice creation and/or overriding of certain methods like doGET in a HTTPServlet? As far as I have seen, this is only a standalone app and not a usable library. As last resort, I could take a look at the source and build my own Webserver, but I´m currently searching for the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically do it, but without root you won't be able to bind a privileged port such as port 80, or set an OOM killer value to prioritize preserving your server over other things that may want memory.

And of course you won't be able to do much unless the upstream wifi or 3g provider is willing to give you an IP address that's routable by the clients of interest.

Comment: and how? Dynamic IP is no problem, and port can be such as 18384.

Comment: same as how you would on any other linux, modulo some build system headaches if porting a complicated server - so pick a fairly lightweight solution that doesn't have a complicated build system.

Comment: sorry, but that´s too abstract for me right now. I need a concrete solution. If you say 'like on any other linux', then I gotta say that I just created a simple webserver on linux with nearly 10 lines of code - with python. So linux or not isn´t relevant...I need something like HTTPServer on python, but for Java.

Comment: Your ten lines of python would probably work, though it will be a little more tricky to deploy than a similarly short solution in java, which I'm sure you can come up with fairly quickly.  Stack overflow is not a custom solution factory, it's place to ask questions *after* making a little personal research effort.

Comment: Yeah, I´m still sure I can come up with a short solution in Java, but I haven´t found it yet. I tried for at least 2 days now, so I guess a little research effort has happenend. Anyways, thanks for your constructive and precise help.

Comment: If you are that averse to writing anything yourself, I'm sure you can find someone who will, for a fee, create a solution which you can instantiate in less than 10 lines of your own code.

Comment: That's not the point here. I'm just trying to search for possibilities to render a proper decision. But I've already come to it now, so again thank you for your time!

Comment: Good answer! Saved me a futile attempt to build a webserver on a _standard_ http port.